# 2.93 cycles denoising viewport render problem with it just going black

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, denoise

I have updated to the new blender 2.93 and have started 3D modelling within it I am unable to do a have the viewport rendering while I work in cycles because of how pixelated it is and the denoiser just doesn't work and in turn just turns black look at photo below for example. I have also tested this on different computers and with the same problem on them.

[image]

Thx for reading